# Excel IF formula to set maximum and minimum

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a column with certain values and I want to create a second one, in which if the value is bigger than `0,4`, it becomes `0,4` and if the value is less than `0,05`, it becomes `0,05`.

In other words, I am trying to set a minimum and maximum on these values to avoid outliers.

So far I have tried with `IF` and `AND`, but it gives me `FALSE`. This is the formula:

```
=IF(AND(I5<0,05;0,05);IF(AND(I5>0,05;I5);IF(AND(I5>0,4;0,4);IF(AND(I5<0,4;I5);""))))
```

Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=MIN(MAX(I5,0.05),0.4)
```

You don't need any `IF()`s

[image]

Comment: That was easy! Thank you so much !!! Really appreciate it